# Is this data interval or ratio?

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics, ratio

Students at my school can have 0 to n number of absences. We recorded the number of absences of 100 students in Fall 2018 before the intervention. At the beginning of the Fall 2019 school year we offered the same 100 students a prize at the end of the semester if they missed no more than 1 day of school.

I think both the number of absences for each student is on the ratio scale as there is a true 0, and also the difference score of each student is on a ratio scale as well as there is a true 0.

I wanted to clarify this reasoning before I write up a report.

Also, as this is discrete data I don't think I can use the t-test correct?

Comment: Discreteness is not so much of a issue for the t test. I imagine you want to compare absences in 2019 with those in 2018, paired by student. In that instance I would want to check the distribution of differences, which ideally is normal, but may well be at a bit different. That may or may not bite much; hard to say without any sight of the data. The difference between means is the major deal, and you could bootstrap or permute to get a confidence interval.

Comment: @ Nick. Thanks for the quick reply! Do you have any references for the "discreteness is not so much of an issue for the t test"? All textbooks I have mention normality of differences being ok to violate if sample is > 30, but I don't find mention of discreteness of differences being ok to violate. Not saying it's not just that I want to site it. Also, what do you mean by differences between means being a major deal? Thanks again

Comment: The t-test doesn't assume the underlying distribution is continuous: that's why you will have a hard time finding any mention of this in textbooks.  *Good* textbooks, though, do make a point of discussing the scope of applicability of this test and show that the underlying distribution need not be Normal: typically, it shouldn't be too *skewed.*

Comment: What's the t test about if not the difference between the means? At worst, some people want to reduce the difference to one bit of information, whether the means are different. But I would want to know the difference between the means. If you tell me say that absences went down from 0.3 per student to 0.2 per student, that is of interest, and possibly of importance.

Comment: @ Nick. Is the default confidence interval STATA or R outputs with a paired t test derived from a bootstrap or permutation method? Or were you recommending those methods due to the specific characteristics of my data?

Comment: In Stata (not STATA, please) the default confidence interval for the difference between means isn't a bootstrap or permutation result. You'd have to get either of the latter two directly. I can't speak for R, but my guess is that similar comments apply.

Comment: Results from `t.test` in R do not involve re-sampling (simulated permutation test or bootstrapping). // Counts of days absent and their differences are ratio data: four missed days is twice as many as two missed days, and $0$ means 'none' (unlike 0 degrees Celsius).

Answer (score 1):

Here is output from R for 100 fake pairs of data on days missed, `x1` for 2018 and `x2` for 2019. I don't suppose they are at all the same as your data, but I hope
they will do for the purpose of illustration.

```
table(x1)
x1
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  9 
 4 10 31 19 16 11  8  1 
table(x2)
x2
 0  1  2  3  4  6 
19 32 31 11  5  2 
table(x1-x2)
-2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
 1 12 18 20 22 16  8  2  1 
cor(x1,x2)
[1] 0.3889237
```

We can see that the number of students with no absences rose from 4 to 19,
that the number of absences tended to decrease overall, and (from the positive correlation) that intervention did not totally dissuade often-absent
students from skipping class more often than their fellow students.

For such data, there is no difficulty using a one-sided paired t test to find whether
the trend toward fewer absences in the second year is statistically significant. The null hypothesis (no effect of intervention) is rejected with a P-value
very near 0.

```
t.test(x1, x2, pair=T, alt="g")

        Paired t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = 8.8598, df = 99, p-value = 1.671e-14
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.186385      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                   1.46
```

Although I see no difficulty using a paired t test, a paired Wilcoxon (signed rank) test also finds a highly significant decrease in absences for my fake data.

```
 wilcox.test(x1, x2, pair=T, alt="g")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
V = 3161, p-value = 4.54e-12
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

Below is a scatterplot of the data with 'jittering' (small random displacements) to avoid plotting many points directly on top of each other. The moderate association in number of absences between the two years is evident. Most points fall below the 45-degree red line, indicating
that absences tended to decrease in the second year.

[image]

*Note;* R code used to generate fake data and to make the scatterplot is shown below.

```
set.seed(1234)  # for reproducibility of data
x1 = rbinom(100, 70, .05)
x2 = rbinom(100, x1+2, .3)

# unknown seed for jittering
X1 = x1 + runif(100, -.1,.1)
X2 = x2 + runif(100, -.1,.1)
plot(X1, X2, pch=20)
 abline(0,1, col="green")
```

Comment: Thanks that was extremely helpful. For the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test I have 13 ties out of 77 difference values. Do you know how to run WSRT including the ties in R?

Comment: Implementations of the one-sample Wilcoxon test in many statistical software programs (including R) can give useful P-values for ties in samples of moderate size. (Often there is a warning message if not.) So I would not be surprised if you got a useful result. // If you can describe your 77 differences and show results from R (or whatever software you're using), then one of us might be able to offer a useful opinion.